# Нежелательная запятая в php-выходе

Tags: php, html

Мой код выводится правильно, но в конце появляется нежелательная запятая. 
[image]

Есть ли способ не получить (или отобразить) последнюю запятую?

```
<?php 
    include 'fortnite-api/Autoloader.php';

    $api = new FortniteClient;

    $api->setKey('66d907e8745cfe491729dc5e4397b54f');
?>
```

Ссылка на весь сайт: http://www.mediafire.com/file/eq0nkhwtv0vq058/jz-software.zip/file

Comment: Непонятно, какое отношение эта картинка имеет к этому коду. Нужен [mcve], при запуске которого мы увидим эту запятую

Comment: Добавил архив со всем сайтом

Comment: Нужен **минимальный** воспроизводимый пример, а не весь сайт. Выкиньте всё, что не относится к проблеме с запятой

Comment: Если кусок кода, приведённый в вопросе, и вправду приводит к появлению запятой, то лучше просто так и скажите

Comment: А впрочем нашёл — [запятая в файле Leaderboard.php](https://github.com/samhoogantink/Fortnite-API/blob/master/fortnite-api/src/Leaderboard.php#L35). Отправьте багрепорт в Fortnite API или просто сотрите запятую у себя (и да, это не отменяет моих предыдущих комментариев)

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83?s=1|48.1407

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файл:

`\fortnite-api\src\Leaderboard.php`

В конце файла:

```
?>,
```

Та самая запятая, которую можно просто удалить.